# workflow fails when adding data from one db to another in oracle

Tags: workflow, designer, informatica, informatica-powercenter

checked in sql developer to confirm table existence and also granted insert, select to the table. help pls!

workflow log -

Severity    Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   9140    LM_36435    Starting execution of workflow [wf_employee_employee] in folder [training] last saved by user [Administrator].
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX9140   LM_44206    Workflow wf_employee_employee started with run id [24], run instance name [], run type [Concurrent Run Disabled].
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   9140    LM_44195    Workflow [wf_employee_employee] service level [SLPriority:5,SLDispatchWaitTime:1800].
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   9140    LM_44253    Workflow started. Clients will be notified
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   9140    LM_36330    Start task instance [Start]: Execution started.
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   9140    LM_36318    Start task instance [Start]: Execution succeeded.
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   9140    LM_36505    Link [Start --> s_M_Employee_Employee]: empty expression string, evaluated to TRUE.
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   9140    LM_36388    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee] is waiting to be started.
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   10416   LM_36682    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee]: started a process with pid [1240] on node [node01_XX].
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   10416   LM_36330    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee]: Execution started.
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   6588    LM_36488    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee] : [TM_6793 Fetching initialization properties from the Integration Service. : (Thu Nov 02 22:40:59 2017)]
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   6588    LM_36488    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee] : [DISP_20305 The [Preparer] DTM with process id [1240] is running on node [node01_XX].
 : (Thu Nov 02 22:40:59 2017)]
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   6588    LM_36488    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee] : [PETL_24036 Beginning the prepare phase for the session.]
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   6588    LM_36488    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee] : [TM_6721 Started [Connect to Repository].]
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   6588    LM_36488    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee] : [TM_6722 Finished [Connect to Repository].  It took [0.0635259] seconds.]
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX6588   LM_36488    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee] : [TM_6794 Connected to repository [infa_training] in domain [Domain_XX] as user [Administrator] in security domain [Native].]
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   6588    LM_36488    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee] : [TM_6721 Started [Fetch Session from Repository].]
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX6588   LM_36488    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee] : [TM_6722 Finished [Fetch Session from Repository].  It took [0.062696] seconds.]
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   6588    LM_36488    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee] : [TM_6721 Started [Partition Group Formation].]
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   6588    LM_36488    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee] : [TM_6722 Finished [Partition Group Formation].  It took [0.00900602] seconds.]
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   6588    LM_36488    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee] : [PETL_24037 Finished the prepare phase for the session.]
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   6588    LM_36488    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee] : [TM_6792 Notifying the Integration Service that the prepare phase has been completed. : (Thu Nov 02 22:40:59 2017)]
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   6588    LM_36488    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee] : [TM_6228 Writing session output to log file [C:\Informatica\961\server\infa_shared\SessLogs\s_M_Employee_Employee.log].]
**ERROR 11/2/2017 10:41:01 PM   node01_XX   15248   LM_36320    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee]: Execution failed.
WARNING 11/2/2017 10:41:01 PM   node01_XX   15248   LM_36331    Session task instance [s_M_Employee_Employee] failed and its "fail parent if this task fails" setting is turned on.  So, Workflow [wf_employee_employee] will be failed.
ERROR   11/2/2017 10:41:02 PM   node01_XX   9164    LM_36320    Workflow [wf_employee_employee]: Execution failed.**

session log -

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES_TEST(EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID)  VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8124    Target Table EMPLOYEES_TEST :SQL UPDATE statement:
UPDATE EMPLOYEES_TEST SET FIRST_NAME = ?, LAST_NAME = ?, EMAIL = ?, PHONE_NUMBER = ?, HIRE_DATE = ?, JOB_ID = ?, SALARY = ?, COMMISSION_PCT = ?, MANAGER_ID = ?, DEPARTMENT_ID = ? WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = ?
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8124    Target Table EMPLOYEES_TEST :SQL DELETE statement:
DELETE FROM EMPLOYEES_TEST WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = ?
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8270    Target connection group #1 consists of target(s) [EMPLOYEES_TEST]
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8003    Writer initialization complete.
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XXREADER_1_1_1   BLKR_16007  Reader run started.
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8005    Writer run started.
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8158

*****START LOAD SESSION*****

Load Start Time: Thu Nov 02 22:40:59 2017

Target tables:

```
 EMPLOYEES_TEST
```

INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX READER_1_1_1  RR_4010 SQ instance [SQ_EMPLOYEES1] SQL Query [SELECT EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME, EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME, EMPLOYEES.EMAIL, EMPLOYEES.PHONE_NUMBER, EMPLOYEES.HIRE_DATE, EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID, EMPLOYEES.SALARY, EMPLOYEES.COMMISSION_PCT, EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID, EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID FROM EMPLOYEES]
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   READER_1_1_1    RR_4049 RR_4049 SQL Query issued to database : (Thu Nov 02 22:40:59 2017)
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   READER_1_1_1    RR_4050 RR_4050 First row returned from database to reader : (Thu Nov 02 22:40:59 2017)
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   READER_1_1_1    BLKR_16019  Read [107] rows, read [0] error rows for source table [EMPLOYEES] instance name [EMPLOYEES1]
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   READER_1_1_1    BLKR_16008  Reader run completed.
**INFO  11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8167    Start loading table [EMPLOYEES_TEST] at: Thu Nov 02 22:40:59 2017
****ERROR   11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8229    Database errors occurred: 
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist***
Database driver error...
Function Name : Prepare DPL
SQL Stmt : INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES_TEST(EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID)  VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
Oracle Fatal Error
Database driver error...
Function Name : Execute Multiple
SQL Stmt : INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES_TEST(EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID)  VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
Oracle Fatal Error
ERROR   11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   WRITER_1__1    WRT_8425    ERROR: Writer execution failed.
ERROR   11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8076    Writer run terminated. [Commit Error]
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8333    Rolling back all the targets due to fatal session error.
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8325    Final rollback executed for the target [EMPLOYEES_TEST] at end of load
ERROR   11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8081    Writer run terminated. [Error in loading data to target table [EMPLOYEES_TEST]]
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8168    End loading table [EMPLOYEES_TEST] at: Thu Nov 02 22:40:59 2017
INFO    11/2/2017 10:40:59 PM   node01_XX   WRITER_1_*_1    WRT_8035    Load complete time: Thu Nov 02 22:40:59 2017**

Comment: From the session log you've shared, its not possible to see whether the schema informatica is querying on your target db is the same schema that the target EMPLOYEES_TEST table resides on. If they aren't the same schema, then apart from grants you'll also have to define synonyms pointing it to the correct schema.

Comment: grant insert, select, update, delete on EMPLOYEES_TEST to public; still same issue

Comment: I don't want to sound like a broken record but whom have you granted this access to and have you defined the synonym I mentioned

Comment: yes created synonym to both tables and grant was provided

Comment: both the tables reside in different schema....source is in HR and target is in TARGET

Comment: Ok, go to the mapping tab in the session task of the workflow, select your target from the left pane and check which connection is being used for the TARGET table. When you can see that, check lookup that connection from Connections in the menu and check the schemaname for that connection

Comment: finally resolved! edited the schemaname for connection and retried. thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the table using schema name like Schema.tableName or else you create a synonym of the table for your informatica user